# name 'cc_library' is not defined

Tags: c++, bazel

Trying to build a C++ library in C++ and I've successfully confused myself

`tools/vector_gen.bzl`

```
def drake_cc_vector_gen_library(
        name,    
        srcs = [],
        deps = [],
        **kwargs):
    generated = cc_vector_gen(
        name = name + "_codegen",
        srcs = srcs,
        include_prefix = "drake",
        drake_workspace_name = "",
        visibility = [],
    )
    cc_library(
        name = name,
        srcs = generated.srcs,
        hdrs = generated.hdrs,
        deps = deps + generated.deps,
        **kwargs
    )
```

`project/BUILD.bazel`

```
load("//tools:vector_gen.bzl", "cc_vector_gen_library")

cc_vector_gen_library(
    name = "x",
    srcs = [
      "x.yaml",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

---

However when I try to do `bazel build //...` at the top of the directory I get

```
ERROR: /root/doublependulum/tools/vector_gen.bzl:170:5: name 'cc_library' is not defined
ERROR: Skipping '.': error loading package 'double_pendulum': Extension 'tools/vector_gen.bzl' has errors
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: Extension 'tools/vector_gen.bzl' has errors
```

I don't think I understand. Isn't `cc_library` always defined? Otherwise how can I import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a .bzl file the builtin definitions need to be qualified as native.cc_library